# container size according to screen

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Hi I created 3 containers but when I use a different device it obviously doesn't scale properly. How can I set as a Container as a specific size to any device. This is my code.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Welcome to my app"),
        ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(450.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0)),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
            color: Colors.grey[600],
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
          ),

        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use Mediaquery widget

Answer (score 1):

Use **`MediaQuery`** widget:-

```
   Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100, // set this calculation as per your requirement
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.teal,
            height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200, // set this calculation as per your requirement
          ),
```

Comment: I get an error saying "MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery."

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Expanded Widgets and give it flex according to your requirements.
also you can use this flutter plugin to provide width and height in terms of %.

https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_flutter

// Example 20% of screen's width
ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).wp(20)

// Example 20% of screen's height
ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).hp(20)

Comment: I get an error saying "MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery."